# C++: Static assert that a parameter pack matches a function type

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, static-assert, parameter-pack

Given the function type `void()`, `void(int)`, and so on..., can we `static_assert()` that `Args&&... args` is compatible with the function type?

```
template <typename F = void(), typename... Args>
auto call(Args&&... args)
{
    // TODO: check if F is compatible with Args

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, decltype(func(args...))>)
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    else
        return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Using `decltype(func(args...))` will give an error, but it's not the best error. Also, is it possible that the `static_assert()` will make it worse by hiding the two types from the compiler output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tagged C++17, so... what about using `std::is_invocable`?

I suppose something as follows

```
template <typename F = void(), typename... Args>
auto call (Args && ... args)
 {
   static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...> );

   // ...
 }
```